# Django Queryset get all values and first related

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to get a json response with "customer" fields and the first phone number associated.

```
# models.py
class Customer(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    ...

class CustomerPhone(models.Model):
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name = 'phones', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    ...
```

My customer can have more phone numbers but in summary table I would like to see only the first phone (with min id)

When I try with this queryset:

```
Customer.objects.all().values('surname','phones__phone_number')
```

I obtain

```
<QuerySet [{'surname': 'Gates', 'phones__phone_number': '+39123456789'}, {'surname': 'Gates', 'phones__phone_number': '+3998765431'}, {'surname': 'Trump', 'phones__phone_number': '+32123456001'}, {'surname': 'Trump', 'phones__phone_number': '+3298765000'}]>
```

What I can obtain only one result for customer with only one phone number?
what can I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`SubQuery`** expresssion [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Customer.objects.values('surname').annotate(
    phone_number=Subquery(
        CustomerPhone.objects.filter(
            customer_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('pk').values('phone_number')[:1]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship between `CustomerPhone` and `Customer` is a `ForeignKey`, so `Customer` will have a `customer_phone_set` field. What you need to do is:

```
 customer = Customer.objects.get(surname="example")
 first_phone_number = customer.customer_phone_set.first()
```